# Replacing same keyword with different strings per line

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, lsblk

I'm using the following command to return a list of available disks and whether they're ssd or rotational (basically replacing 0 and 1 in lsblk's output with their actual meaning):

```
lsblk -d -o name,ro | sed "s/RO/\ TYPE/; s/NAME/DISK/; s/0/SSD/g; s/1/ROT/g"
```

sample output:

```
DISK  TYPE
sda   SSD
sdb   ROT
```

Now I'd like to add another column, "rm", to `lsblk` (`lsblk -d -o name,ro,rm`) but it also uses 0 and 1 to mean a different thing (0=fixed disk, 1=removable).

Is there a way to use sed (or awk or anything else) to replace 0 and 1's in the third column with YES and NO?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`Awk`** approach:

```
lsblk -d -o name,ro,rm \
| awk 'NR == 1{ print "DISK TYPE REMOVABLE"; split("SSD ROT", ro); split("NO YES", rm); next}
      { print $1, ro[$2+1], rm[$3+1] }'
```

Sample output:

```
DISK TYPE REMOVABLE
sda SSD NO
sr0 SSD YES
```

Comment: Both answers valid, but choosing this one for the smarter approach (didn't know about split). Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

try

```
lsblk -d -o name,ro,rm |
   awk '$2 == 0 { $2 = "SSD" ; } $2 == 1 { $2 = "ROT" ; }
        $3 == 0 { $3 = "NO" ; } $3  == 1 { $3 = "YES" ;}
        { print ; }'
```

- this can be one-lined.
- sometime people use `1` instead of `{ print ; }`.
- changing `RO` to `TYPE` is left as an exercice.